# Django model Attributes for Booking system

Tags: python, django, model

I'm itermediate in Django ...
I work on Booking system with Django. I have two main models : 1.Service & 2.Reservation

Service is like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4096, null=True, blank=True)
    pic         = models.ImageField(upload_to='category/')
    slug_category = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, max_length=100, unique=True, default='-')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_at']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_category = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class AllService(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug_service = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, max_length=100, unique=True, default='-')
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='service/')
    current_queue = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    max_queue = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='services')
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=1000)
    service_off = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(0.2)])
    
    def full_queue(self):
        if self.current_queue > self.max_queue:
            self.is_available = False
    
    @property
    def remaining_queue(self):
        return (self.max_queue - self.current_queue)
    
    def adding_in_queue(self):
        k = self.current_queue
        k += 1
        self.current_queue = k
        return self.current_queue
    
    def reset_queue(self):
        if datetime.now()==time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0.00):
            self.current_queue=0
            self.active=True

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category} {self.title} {self.current_queue}"
```

and the Reservation is like this :

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reservations')
    service = models.ForeignKey(AllService, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reservation')
    pick_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} {self.service}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        
    def clean(self):
        if self.pick_date < timezone.localdate():
            raise ValidationError("day was passed")
        else:
            return super().clean()
    
    def adding_user_to_queue(self):
        AllService.adding_in_queue()
```

what I try to do is :
when someone choose a service in the Reservation model the "adding_user_to_queue" triger the "adding_in_queue()" method and add up the current_queue field by one, but it doesn't work!
I see this Idea from this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932056/django-reservation-system" but it does not explain how to do that and I even test the views.py to handle this, but it didn't work too, maybe I made mistake...
If anyone knows this, please send me a tip or answer,
Thanks for your attention , happy codeing!

I'm trying to handle this on models and for now just in admin panel to get proper result and than work on client side and the rest of it ...

Comment: Where is `self.current_limit` defined ?